# Remove nested json object from array in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a json object field in postgres that has the following shape

```
{
"a": {
   
},
"b": [
    {
        
    }
],
"c": {
    "d": "",
    "e": [
        {
            "id": 1234,
            "f": "",
            "g": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I'd like to know how to  write a statement that removes object's from e array where the id is 1234 in postgres. e could have multiple objects, if there are more than one objects in the e array, I want to keep those and only remove the object with the id of 1234.

Thanks

Comment: Will it always be under keys c and e?

Comment: Yes it will always be under keys c and e @Schwern

Answer (score 1):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=634acd1bbca036b851a5f8c347d77b7b)

```
UPDATE t 
SET data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, '{c,e}', s.new_array::jsonb)::json   -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT
        json_agg(value) as new_array                   -- 3
    FROM
        t,
        json_array_elements(data -> 'c' -> 'e')        -- 1
    WHERE value ->> 'id' != '1234'                     -- 2
) s;
```

1. To remove a certain element from a JSON array, you need to expand it into on row per array element
2. Remove the record with the element you want to delete
3. Reaggregate the JSON array
4. If you want to do an `UPDATE` on your table, you could use the `jsonb_set()` function to update the JSON element with your newly created array. Unless you are not using type `jsonb`, you have to case your JSON data into `jsonb` (and the result back to type `json`)