# Remove objects from json subarray of array

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-json

I have a table:

```
create table public.config
(
    id         text                                   not null,
    payload    json                                   not null,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);
```

and the `json` field has the following structure:

```
{
    "QuestsCommon":
    [
        {
            "QuestType": "Standard",
            "RotationQuestsList": []
        },
        {
            "QuestType": "Daily", ️ need to remove elements from subarray ("RotationQuestsList") where  "QuestType" == "Daily"
            "RotationQuestsList":
            [
                {
                    "QuestId": "1", ️ need to remove array's element with "QuestId" == 1
                    "GroupId": "Reusable",
                    "Enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "QuestId": "2",
                    "GroupId": "Reusable",
                    "Enabled": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "QuestType": "Weekly",
            "RotationQuestsList": []
        },
        {
            "QuestType": "Challenge",
            "RotationQuestsList":
            [
                {
                    "QuestId": "Lucky",
                    "GroupId": "Regular",
                    "Enabled": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd to write a query that removes object's from the subarray (`RotationQuestsList` ) of the `QuestsCommon` array by `QuestType` of the parent array and `QuestId` of the subarray (QuestId == 1, for example).

I found answers like  [Remove nested json object from array in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65195386/8030651) and [How to remove object from json array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84495), but stuck anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH updated_quests_common AS(
    SELECT id, json_agg(
        CASE WHEN element->>'QuestType' != 'Daily' THEN element
        ELSE json_build_object('QuestType', 'Daily', 'RotationQuestsList', (
            SELECT json_agg(inner_element) FROM json_array_elements((element->>'RotationQuestsList')::json) AS inner_element
            WHERE (inner_element->>'QuestId')::int != 1
        )) -- this json_build_object need additional work if you have more keys than you provide
        END
    ) quests_common
    FROM config,
         json_array_elements((payload->>'QuestsCommon')::json) AS element
    GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE config SET payload = (payload::jsonb || jsonb_build_object('QuestsCommon', updated_quests_common.quests_common))::json
FROM updated_quests_common
WHERE config.id = updated_quests_common.id;
```

Edit: forgot about second condition (need to remove array's element with "QuestId" == 1), hope someone can simplify this.